# React- React-Router is not navigating to edit path and is pre-pending link path to current path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a fairly simple navigation setup. I am running into an issue where if I am on the /ingredients when I click on the edit link, the router is navigating me to /ingredients/edit/Ingredients/:id instead of ingredients/edit/:id (note :id is just some random guid).

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <MenuBar />
      {isLoading && (
        <div className={"spinnerContainer"}>
          <CircularProgress className={"spinner"} />
        </div>
      )}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/ingredients/edit/:id" component={IngredientEdit} />
        <Route exact path="/ingredients/:id" component={IngredientDetail} />
        <Route exact path="/ingredients/" component={IngredientsList} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Below are the links in my list component:

```
                 <Link
                    onClick={() => {
                      dispatch(ingredientIdSelected(x.id));
                      history.push(`/ingredients/edit/${x.id}`);
                    }}
                  >
                      <Edit />
                  </Link>         
                  <Link
                    onClick={() => {
                      dispatch(ingredientIdSelected(x.id));
                      history.push(`/${x.id}`);
                    }}
                  >                       
                      <Info />
                  </Link>
```

On click I dispatch an action and use history.push to navigate user to the relevant component. I am using the **useHistory()** hook instead of using a HOC (i.e. wrapping my components in **withRouter**).

When I am on the /ingredients route, if I click on the detail link (i.e. **history.push(`/${x.id}`)**) I am correctly navigated to /ingredients/:id.

When I click on the edit link, I am being navigated to /ingredients/edit/ingredients/:id. I also tried changing my history.push to **/edit/:id** and that navigates to edit/Ingredients/:id.

For whatever reason, the current path is being stored and checked against. How do I set it up so it routes correctly?

---

The MenuBar component is a static menu bar that just routes to the root component (i.e. IngredientsList).

Below is the component the links are located in (the IngredientList component)

```
return (
  <>
      {ingredients.map((x, index) => {
        return (
              <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                 {some content here}
              <CardActions>
                    <Link
              onClick={() => {
                dispatch(ingredientIdSelected(x.id));
                history.push(`/ingredients/edit/${x.id}`);
              }}
            >
              <Edit />
            </Link>         
            <Link
              onClick={() => {
                dispatch(ingredientIdSelected(x.id));
                history.push(`/${x.id}`);
              }}
            >                       
              <Info />
            </Link>
                  </CardActions>
            </Card>
        )})}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Are these links in the `MenuBar` component, or elsewhere? Can you update your question to include the component code rendering the `Link` components? I don't think your other `history.push(\`/${x.id}\`)` is working correctly either as it *should* push "/someIdValue", not "/ingredients/someIdValue". If possible, and minimal, *running* codesandbox example that reproduces the issue we could live debug in would be helpful.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the component. The links are in the List component. The MenuBar component only contains top level routes. I'll see if I can get a demo working on a sandbox